# How to generate a date timestamp in PHP in this format "2013-11-16T12:30:00+02:00"?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Hi how can i generate a date timestamp in PHP in this format "2013-11-16T12:30:00+02:00" ?

Comment: A timestamp has no format. You can get a timestamp from a string with that format, though. Or you can get a date formatted with that format from a given timestamp.

Comment: I have added answer please check

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [DateTime::ATOM](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$time = new DateTime;
echo $time->format(DateTime::ATOM);
//2015-10-07T10:18:48+00:00
```

If you want a specific date, use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), i.e.:

```
$raw = '22. 11. 1968';
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y', $raw);
echo $time->format(DateTime::ATOM);
//1968-11-22T10:33:10+00:00
```

---

Some predefined `Constants` of the `DateTime` class are:

**DateTime::ATOM**
DATE_ATOM
    Atom (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00)

**DateTime::COOKIE**
DATE_COOKIE
    HTTP Cookies (example: Monday, 15-Aug-2005 15:52:01 UTC)

**DateTime::ISO8601**
DATE_ISO8601
    ISO-8601 (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000)

**DateTime::RFC822**
DATE_RFC822
    RFC 822 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000)

**DateTime::RFC850**
DATE_RFC850
    RFC 850 (example: Monday, 15-Aug-05 15:52:01 UTC)

**DateTime::RFC1036**
DATE_RFC1036
    RFC 1036 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000)

**DateTime::RFC1123**
DATE_RFC1123
    RFC 1123 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000)

**DateTime::RFC2822**
DATE_RFC2822
    RFC 2822 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000)

**DateTime::RFC3339**
DATE_RFC3339
    Same as DATE_ATOM (since PHP 5.1.3)

**DateTime::RSS**
DATE_RSS
    RSS (example: Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000)

**DateTime::W3C**
DATE_W3C
    World Wide Web Consortium (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get date timestamp format

```
echo date(DATE_ATOM,mktime(0,0,0,10,3,2015));// prints 2015-10-03T00:00:00+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's simple

> date('c')